# Passing a 'command with a pipe' as a bash function parameter

Tags: bash, unix, pipe, parameter-passing

I've written a tiny bash function which simply runs a command if `$current_user_input = yes`

```
function if_yes_run_with {
    if [ $current_user_input = yes ]
    then
        $1
    fi
}
```

I call it a number of times perfectly fine e.g:

```
if_yes_run_with 'brew update'
```

however, I've reached a point where I'd like to pass a command to it that includes a pipe:

```
if_yes_run_with '\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable'
```

the function appears to only evaluate command up to the pipe. The outcome of running it therefore gives the same result as:

```
if_yes_run_with \curl -L https://get.rvm.io
```

Can anyone help with passing a 'command with a pipe' as a parameter to a bash function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to do what you want in a safe and robust way. [Greg's Bash Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) says it best:

> Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables!

I wouldn't have it execute the command directly. Instead, have the function return success/failure. Then you can do whatever you like at the calling end with `&&` or `if`.

```
is_user_input_enabled() {
    [[ $current_user_input = yes ]]
}

is_user_input_enabled && brew update
is_user_input_enabled && curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Notice how you don't need any extra quotes or escaping to make this work.

See also:

- [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)
- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)
- [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)